# Render XAML into video or PNG files?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an application with a complex animation in XAML as a background, and it's slowing it down considerably.

Is there a simple way to export XAML to video or a series of PNG files?
Would this help performance, replacing the XAML with a video?

Comment: So you know, a hidden feature of SO is that you can use two spaces at the end of a line instead of `<br/>`.  Not sure this is documented anywhere...

Comment: wow, thanks. been looking for that.

Comment: a video wouldn't scale nice - are you sure this is what you want ?

Comment: Yes, this is an application for a kiosk, the display resolution is fixed.

Comment: Could you not just use screen recording software on a fast machine? There are some free options out there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank video, put it in Expression Encoder, and add the XAML as an overlay.
Not the most elegant solution, but works.